# Find 'li' element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Could someone please assist me in order to find 5th '**li**' element since that receiving error when trying to locate it. Following is how looks on page:

```
<ul class="navigation-primary navigation-primary--right js-navigation-primary">
<li><a data-modal="login-modal" href="javascript:void(0);" data-modal-content-switch="login-options" class="is-button-group-right js-prevent-trigger modal-content-button"><span>Logga in</span></a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="icon icons8-Search has-no-border-bottom" data-menu="search"></a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="has-no-border-bottom" data-menu="language">Svenska</a></li>
```

Actually, I need  last one with following attribute

```
data-menu="language"
```

Since there are several languages - I suppose that it would solve with **if** loop:

```
if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="header"]/div[2]/div/ul[2]/li[5]/a") != null
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="header"]/div[2]/div/ul[2]/li[5]/a").click();
else {
 system.out.println("element not present");

 }
```

Since that there are several languages and every has last **li[5]** - thought that lang name could solve it, but did not find solution.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you sum up your exact manual steps you are trying to Automate? I don't see any 5th `<li>` as such. All together I can see 3 `<li>` tags. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DebanjanB Ups, my mistake - 3 li tags are indeed, not 5 - just wrote question without correct count. Sorry

Comment: So which `<li>` element do you want to locate/find?

Comment: @DebanjanB this one
        class="has-no-border-bottom" data-menu="language"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you accepted an answer but it would be a lot cleaner and clearer if you used a simple CSS selector like

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[data-menu='language']")).click();
```

or you could be more specific and find the element by language using XPath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-menu='language'][.='Svenska']")).click();
```

Also, you can't check if an element is `null`. If it's not there, `.findElement()` will just throw an exception. If you want to check if an elements exists, use `.findElements()` and check to see if the collection is empty

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(...);
if (links.isEmpty())
{
    // element doesn't exist
}
else
{
    // element exists
    links[0].click(); // or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the `HTML` you provided the following `xpath`/`cssSelector`should work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='navigation-primary navigation-primary--right js-navigation-primary']/li[contains(.,'Svenska')]"));
```

> OR

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.navigation-primary.navigation-primary--right.js-navigation-primary > li.navigation-primary.navigation-primary--right.js-navigation-primary"));
```

Answer (score -1):

At the risk of redefining your question, I'd be tempted to add some `id` tags into your html and call `driver.findElement(By.id(name))`.

The advantage is that if an extra item is added to the start of list then your tests will not break.